# How to show the questions with the appropriate type (text, checkbox, select, etc)? (the input type text and textarea are not appearing)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a form for a user create custom questions. For that the user needs to introduce the question (ex: Receive notifications?) and also the type of field (text, long text, checkbox, select menu, radio button). If the user selects a field of checkbox, select menu or radio button he also need to introduce the available options for the question.

In the database the questions are inserted in the questions and question_options tables like:

//questions table

```
id     question                    type          conference_id      
1       question1                 text                 1
2       question2                long_text             1   
3       question3                checkbox              1  
4       question4                radio_btn             1  
5       question5                select_menu           1
```

//question_options table:

```
id     question_id                   type                
1       3                             q3op1       
2       3                              q3op2
3       4                             q4op1 
4       4                              q4op2 
5       5                              q5op1      
6       5                              q5op2
```

My doubt is how to show properly in the registration.blade.php the inputs (text, radio button, checkbox, select, textarea and input file) based on the type stored in the column "type" of the questions table.

For now, is not working properly it is appearing like the left screen of the image but should appear like the right screen of the image, that is the issue is that the input type text and textarea are not appearing.

[image]

The code that I have for now is below and besides the issue of not appearing the form elements input type text and textarea in the view the code also don't seems very correct because the Question model has the getHtmlInput() that is returning html.

Do you know how this can be better achieved using MVC? Or if in this case is ok to use the getHtmlInput() in the Question model how to fix the code to work properly, that is, show also the input type text and textarea?

Question Model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'type', 'conference_id',
    ];

    public static $typeHasOptions = [
        'radio_btn',
        'select_menu',
        'checkbox'
    ];

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }

    public function options() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionOption');
    }

    public function hasOptions() {
        return in_array($this->type, self::$typeHasOptions);
    }


    public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype=false)
    {
        $html = '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='participant_question' class='form-control' ".($required?:" required").">" : '';


        foreach($options as $option) {

            switch ($customtype) {

                case "text":

                    $html .= " 
                <div class='form-group'>
                  <label class='text-heading font-weight-semi-bold'>$option->value</label>
                    <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required?:" required") . ">".
                "</div>";


        break;
    case "checkbox":
        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='".$option->value."' class='form-check-input'" . ($required?:" required") . ">".
                    '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value. '</label>'.

                "</div>";
        break;
    case "radio_btn":
        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='".$option->value."' class='form-check-input'" . ($required?:" required") . ">".
            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value. '</label>'.

            "</div>";
        break;
    case "select_menu":
        $html .= "<option value='".$option->value."'>";
        break;
    case "textarea":
        $html .= "
          <div class='form-group'>
                <textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required?:" required") . ">"
                    . $option->value .
                "</textarea>
        </div>";

        break;

            }
        }

        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

QuestionOption model:

```
class QuestionOption extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'question_id', 'value' ];

    public function question() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }
}
```

Code to show the form elements in the registration.blade.php view using the getHTMLInput():

```
if ($allParticipants == 0)
    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
            @if($customQuestion->hasOptions())
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    $customQuestion->options,
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}
            @endif
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                   name="participant_question_id[]"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Generated html with current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/7qa1cnxc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if `$customQuestion->hasOptions()` will return false? You should add else conditions as well and rewrite code as follows:

```
if ($allParticipants == 0)
    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
            @if($customQuestion->hasOptions() && in_array($customQuestion->type, ['checkbox', 'radio_btn', 'select_menu']))
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    $customQuestion->options,
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}

            @else
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    [],
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}    
            @endif
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                   name="participant_question_id[]"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Use this function as:

```
public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype = false) {
    $html = '';
    $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='participant_question' class='form-control' " . ($required ?: " required") . ">" : '';

    if (empty($options)) {
        switch ($customtype) {
            case "text":
                $html .= "<input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">";
                break;

            case "long_text":
                $html .= "<textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">". $name ."</textarea>";

                break;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            switch ($customtype) {
                case "checkbox":
                    $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                    break;
                case "radio_btn":
                    $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                    break;
                case "select_menu":
                    $html .= "<option value='" . $option->value . "'>'" . $option->value . "'</option>";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in Question model in this line " foreach($options as $option) {".

Comment: With that error, the layout doesn't appear so I don't know if the input type text and textarea are already appearing.

Comment: It appears "Undefined variable: option" in " $html .= "  <div class='form-group'> <label class='text-heading font-weight-semi-bold'>$option->value</label> <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" . "</div>";".

Comment: Thanks, do you know why the parameter $name here "public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype = false) {
" is necessary? Because it seems that is not used.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the logic is that text inputs (and textarea) simply don't have options.  It's free to write what you like.

Issues:

- The view code only renders anything visible if it has options
- The return variable (``$html`) inside getHtmlInput is populated inside a loop over the options

Neither of these will work for text/textarea inputs which don't have options.

In terms of returning HTML for the options from the model, I personally think it can be valid in this kind of situation as long as it's minimal mark-up - and consistent. You need to think about the labels, for example.  You currently have one in the view (with a hard-coded *for* attribute) and then another in the getHtmlInput (also with hard-code for in the case of checkbox, but no for for text inputs).

In general you have a few options here:

- Return minimal html for the control from the question model
- Expose the options and types (and maybe properties like generated ids to use in both input and label) and implement all the mark-up in the template.  Might be a good idea to do a formal model for an option in this case
- Implement each question type as a child model with it's own view, which you then include from the master view.  Or have the model select different views based on type at least.

The first option is often "good enough" but the second two are more formally correct MVC.  Last is in some ways cleanest, since you keep the views since you keep the views clean and free of logic but don't return mark-up from the model.  But it can be considered overkill.

Comment: Thanks, maybe if in this scenario is ok to have the getHtmlInput() in the  Question model and it's +- working can you show what needs to be different in get getHtmlInput() to also show the input type text and textarea?